# Microsoft SQL Server migration and users conflict resolution?

Tags: sql-server, authentication

When moving a server from one machine to another, it is necessary to re-create the SQL Server users from the old machine.

But when moving databases, they are moved with those users already in.

Problem is that the "new" SQL users do not map to the same users on the databases. What is the best way to fix this (other than removing all users from databases and re-creating them)?

Dropping all users and re-creating them works, but it's slow. I need a more efficient method of dealing with this. A script that does it perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Normally I would use sp_helprevlogin to copy the users from instance A to B. Not sure how it will react if the users are already created.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/security/transfer-logins-passwords-between-instances

Answer (score -1):

You simply need to create SQL Login on a new machine and re-link users with logins. The below microsoft's article shows how to find and fix such users:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/troubleshoot-orphaned-users-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

You simply need to create a cursor that will iterate through each orphaned user, and for each of them it will firstly create a login and then it will link that login with existing user.